# OpenRewrite: problem with custom Recipe and doAfterVisit method

Tags: openrewrite

I am trying to make a custom recipe with the following logic:

If I find a specific value for a property found in a yaml file, then I add a maven dependency to pom.xml.

In principle it seems to be an easy case, but I can't get it to work...

For this I have created the following recipe:

```
public class CustomRecipe extends Recipe {


  public CustomRecipe() {}


  @Override
  protected TreeVisitor<?, ExecutionContext> getSingleSourceApplicableTest() {
    return new HasSourcePath<>("**/application-*.yml");
  }

  @Override
  public YamlVisitor<ExecutionContext> getVisitor() {
    return new YamlIsoVisitor<ExecutionContext>() {
      @Override
      public Yaml.Mapping.Entry visitMappingEntry(final Yaml.Mapping.Entry entry, final ExecutionContext context) {
        final Yaml.Mapping.Entry e = super.visitMappingEntry(entry, context);
        if (e.getValue() instanceof Yaml.Scalar && ((Yaml.Scalar) e.getValue()).getValue().contains("ENC(")) {
          // if jasypt usage is found in a .yml file then the Jasypt starter is added to pom.xml.
          this.doAfterVisit(
              new AddDependency("com.google.guava", "guava", "29.X", null, null, null,
                  null, null, null, null, null));
        }
        return e;
      }
    };
  }

}
```

After correctly configuring the plugin in the final project to run the above recipe and running the `mvn rewrite:run` command in DEBUG mode I notice that the yaml visitor correctly runs through the yaml file properties, including finding the property value, and therefore the maven recipe `AddDependency` is added in the `this.doAfterVisit(...)` method.

However, the dependency is never added to the pom.xml of the project...

I'm new to OpenRewrite and maybe I'm not understanding correctly how to do this...

any ideas?

I am using:

- maven 3.6.3
- Open rewrite plugin: 4.23.0
- Open rewrite: 7.22.0

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have found a way to do what I wanted to do:

Use `doNext` instead of `doAfterVisit` to glue the Recipe to add the Maven dependency. Also, some parameters were missing to add to the `AddDependency` recipe like `version` and `ifOnlyUsing`:

```
    @Override
    public YamlVisitor<ExecutionContext> getVisitor() {
      return new YamlIsoVisitor<ExecutionContext>() {
        @Override
        public Yaml.Mapping.Entry visitMappingEntry(final Yaml.Mapping.Entry entry, final ExecutionContext context) {
          final Yaml.Mapping.Entry e = super.visitMappingEntry(entry, context);
          if (e.getValue() instanceof Yaml.Scalar && ((Yaml.Scalar) e.getValue()).getValue().startsWith("ENC(")) {
            CustomRecipe.this.doNext(new AddDependency("com.google.guava", "guava",
                "29.X" , null, null, false, "org.junit.jupiter.api.*", null, null, false, null);
          }
          return e;
        }
      };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research i was able to reproduce similar issue and after debugging and throughly following the documentation and github testcases of addDependency openrewrite, found that AddDependency needs one more extra field **onlyIfUsing** which is missing in your constructor.

**onlyIfUsing usage::** As shown in below example link, if there is some import we are using in code, we check for such import to get the desired dependency added to pom.xml.

```
onlyIfUsing : "com.google.common.math.IntMath"
```

https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite/blob/main/rewrite-maven/src/test/java/org/openrewrite/maven/AddDependencyTest.java